# Passport.js google sign in redirected by middleware

Tags: node.js, passport.js

This is the google strategy:

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: config.google_consumer_key,
    clientSecret: config.google_consumer_secret,
    callbackURL: config.google_callback,
    passReqToCallback: true
},
    function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        User.findOrCreate({ 
            email: profile.email, 
            username:`${profile.given_name} ${profile.family_name}` 
        }, function (err, user) {
            user.connected = true;
            user.save();
            return done(err, user);
        });
    }
));
```

and this is the middleware:

```
var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
  if(!req.isAuthenticated()) 
    return res.redirect(301,'/login');
  
  next();
};

module.exports = isAuthenticated;
```

and the route:

```
router.get('/google-signin',
  passport.authenticate('google', 
    { scope: [ 'email', 'profile' ] }
));
```

and the logout

```
logout = async function(req, res){
        req.user.connected = false;
        await req.user.save();
        req.logout();
        return res.redirect('/login');
    }
```

The first time I sign in, there are no problems, but, if I log out and try to sign in again, I'm redirected to `/`. I can't see the problem.

I've set a breakpoint in the middleware and the first time(when it works) the middleware its executed but , when I logout and   try yo login in again the middleware it's not executed

Comment: Can you show your code how you logout?

Comment: Yes ,It's added on the  question

Comment: Where are you using your middleware?

Comment: `/login`  uses  `isAuthenticated` middleware